# Is there an algorithm that answers this

Tags: javascript, algorithm, calendar, logic

Let's say that there are 4 seasons in a year, namely , spring , summer , fall , and winter. Each season has equal no. Of days ; 28. Now , I have this plant that only grows in specific season, the summer. If given two dates (format: SS / DD / YY ), I need to find the number of growing days between those points of time. How can I do that? I found out the formula for getting the Amount of days between two points , its

`grossDays = (( toYear - fromYear )*112) + (( toSeason - fromSeason) *28) + ( toDay - fromDay )`

If spring = 1, summer = 2, fall = 3, winter = 4.
Now the number that I need is the amount of days that the plant can grow.

Example:

From: Spring 14 Year 1
To : Summer 14 Year 2

Gross Days = 150 days

Net Days = 40 Days

( By the way, If you play stardew valley you might have the idea of how I got into this problem )

Comment: Can there more than one season that a plant may grow? If so, is this presented as an array of seasons?

Comment: Does "between" include the two dates?

Comment: Im sorry, the term between only includes the toDate.. I used a wrong word for that... It should be " days after ". And also .... Yes it is an array of seasons

Comment: So 2/1/1 to 2/14/1 should be 13 and not 14?

Comment: Yes it is but the example says that it started at spring. So the first day at summer must also be included. however now that you said that. It is not possible that I can plant before the growing season... so the only growing days is 40 days and not 42. Because the planting day is not included. But I can just count how many times it enters the growing season and subtract it to the total growing days. Although problems will start if there are multiple consecutive growing seasons. But I will just put special cases for that since a plant with multiple growing seasons are uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the growing seasons are part of the input, and can be multiple seasons, here is a function that you could use:

```js
function growingDays(begin, end, growingSeasons) {
    let [season1, day1, year1] = begin.match(/\d\d/g).map(Number);
    let [season2, day2, year2] = end.match(/\d\d/g).map(Number);
    let count = 0;
    // First date must not be later than second date. Otherwise return 0
    if ((year1 * 4 + season1) * 28 + day1 > (year2 * 4 + season2) * 28 + day2) return 0;
    while (season1 !== season2 || day2 < day1) {
        if (growingSeasons.includes(season2)) count += day2;
        day2 = 28;
        season2 = (season2 + 2) % 4 + 1; // previous season
        if (season2 === 4) year2--;
    }
    if (growingSeasons.includes(season1)) count += day2 - day1 + 1;
    return count + (year2 - year1) * 28 * growingSeasons.length;
}

console.log(growingDays("01/14/01", "02/14/02", [2]));
```

In case the day of the begin date should not be included in the count, then change:

```
count += day2 - day1 + 1;
```

to:

```
count += day2 - day1;
```